# iOS: how to change a label alignment based on screen variation

Tags: ios, label, alignment

In IB, there's no way to add a variation on the alignment property of a label.
My need is to align the text on left when width is compact and centered when width is regular.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this behavior to the outlets in

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
switch newCollection.verticalSizeClass {
        case .compact:
            yourLabel.textAligment = UITextAligment.left
        case .regular, .unspecified:
            yourLabel.textAligment = UITextAligment.center
        }
 }
```

For determining rotating you use verticalSizeClass, for determining device type (such iPad or iPhone) you use horizontalSizeClass.

Comment: Unfortunately, IB have a few less possibility for creating and manipulating UI elements than the creating them by code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(width >= yourDesiredWidth){ 
    yourLabel.textAligment = UITextAligment.center
}
else{
    yourLabel.textAligment = UITextAligment.left
}
```